# How to escape these character in powershell [], "", |

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to pass the below entry to cmd line from PowerShell. What to do?

```
["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw$h"]
```

How to write in PowerShell command and can execute in command line?

Comment: The string in your question is not executable in and by itself, so how exactly (with which command) do you want to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd --% /c ["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw$h"]
```

`--%` is an escape sequence, everything after it is passed to the executable unmodified

Comment: It did not help

Comment: well, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, `^` is an escape character in cmd, check updated answer.

Comment: The parameter is `--%`, and it's [not available prior to PowerShell v3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/).

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.exe /C "echo `[`"192.168.10.1`|443`|Atulkatiyar`|passw`$h`"`]"
```

Comment: Nothing is helped The below is my power shell script it will execute on cmd prompt:   $avconfig = "`[`"192.168.1.21`|443`|atulkatiyar`|passw`$h`"`]"
write-host "avconfig:" $avconfig
$configCmd = """c:\Program Files\VMware\vRealize Operations For Horizon\Broker Agent\bin\v4v_brokeragentcfg.exe""" + " /avcfg $avconfig "
write-host "invoking silent config command : cmd /c $configCmd"
Invoke-VMScript -VM $vm -ScriptText "start cmd /c $configCmd" -ScriptType Bat  -GuestUser $UID -GuestPassword $PASSWD -Server $viserver -Confirm:$false  Assume $VM, $UID, $PASSWD , $viserver are provided correct

Comment: If i run the same command manually on cmd windows it works fine "c:\Program Files\VMware\vRealize Operations For Horizon\Broker Agent\bin\v4v_brokeragentcfg.exe" + " /avcfg ["192.168.1.21|443|atulkatiyar`passw$h"]"    i tried hard with all the options and escaped all the special charters. Even getting out put it is same what we are are supposed to provide in cmd prompt but does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by "pass to cmd line".

From PowerShell's perspective, if you want the string in your question to be treated as a *literal*, simply enclose it in `'...'` (single quotes; enclose *embedded* single quotes, if any, as `''`):

```
> '["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw$h"]'
["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw$h"]
```

If you want to pass this literal to `cmd.exe`, the standard command processor, the same applies:

```
> cmd /c echo '["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw$h"]'
["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw$h"]
```

That said, your string contains `$h`, which looks like a reference to a PowerShell variable - if you want that reference expanded (interpolated) first, a different approach is needed; in the following commands, string concatenation with binary operator `+` is used:

```
> $h = 'Hi!'

> ('["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw' + $h + '"]' )
["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passwHi!"]

> cmd /c echo ('["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw' + $h + '"]' )
["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passwHi!"]
```

Alternatively, and generally, you can use *double*-quoted strings to embed variable references (`$<varName>`) and subexpression (`$(...)`) that should be *expanded* (interpolated: replaced by their value) - in that event, use `` ` ``(the backtick) to escape embedded `"` (and `$` characters, if needed):

```
> "[`"192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw$h`"]"
["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passwHi!"]

> cmd /c echo "[`"192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw$h`"]"
["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passwHi!"]
```

---

Other options:

- You can use the binary `-f` operator for string formatting, where the LHS contains placeholders such as `{0}` (the first operand) that are instantiated with the value on the RHS (based on the .NET framework's [`String.Format` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) - see also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)):

```
> ('["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw{0}"]' -f $h)
["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passwHi!"]

> cmd /c echo ('["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passw{0}"]' -f $h)
["192.168.10.1|443|Atulkatiyar|passwHi!"]
```

- In PSv3+, as mentioned, the special `--%` "stop-parsing" switch allows you to pass the remaining parameters through to `cmd.exe` *as-is*, *except* for `cmd.exe`-style environment-variable references such as `%PATH%`; note that this means that PowerShell variable references and subexpressions are then *not* expanded.